# Remote access of an iPad display from another iPad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, remote-desktop, ios, remote-control

I've got an iPad and I was searching for new applications with new features. Currently I'm searching for an application by that I can remotely access another iPad screen just like Teamviewer.

Is there any iPad application available which can be useful to access another iPad's screen.

Comment: Since this would be technically impossible on a non-jailbroken iPad, would you mind jailbreaking?

Comment: Hi Gerry, is it possible after jailbreaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS security sandbox will prevent any App store app from sharing the screen of any other app on a stock iPad.  However the built-in AirPlay mirroring will allow a user to send a mirror of their iPad display to an Apple TV.

Comment: Thank you hotpaw2 for a good technical answer but sometime I need to share the screen of iPad with my client to show my output or check his output of web app I built. In the case we don't have Apple TV I've to immediately check his output. Sometime we got an issue where I got perfect output of the app but the client facing some issue. This is one of reason I'm searching for an app, your point is also valid of security sandbox but like Teamviewer if there are any app for an iPad it would be great. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dhaval he's saying it's not possible due to the sandbox.

Comment: I know Pekka, I'm just replying him what I wanted but if its not possible then let it be :)

Answer (score 1):

A clunky workaround would be to have the client take a screenshot and email or iMessage it to you. Screenshots are taken by pressing the home and sleep buttons at the same time until the screen flashes and you hear the camera noise. The screenshot is saved to your Camera Roll.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for advice I know the way we can take screenshot :) but actually I'm looking for an app to display the whole process of an application I've built. By screenshot we can just capture current state of application on screen.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use reflection on the other person's iPad and then use a desktop viewer on your iPad to view the desktop that is viewing the other person's iPad? You just need a desktop as an intermediary between you both.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer, Joshua! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using RHUB iOS app. You can use it for conducting online meetings and providing remote support. It is free.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried it, but there is an application called [Reflector](http://reflectorapp.com/) that claims:

> Your iPhone or **iPad**. On your Mac or PC.
>
> AirPlay mirror your iPhone 4S, iPad 2 or the new iPad to any Mac or PC, wirelessly.

So you then be able to share your desktop screen with your client, and be in business.

If Reflector doesn't work for you, there are a few [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/reflection/) that offer screen-sharing. Currently the following are listed, though more may be added over time:

- [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/)
- [iDemo](http://www.plutinosoft.com/idemo)

(NB I didn't include a link to *Shairport4w* as says it only streams music)

Comment: Hi Clare, Thanks for the suggestions but the application you suggested is to access any PC Screen from iPad / iPhone. I wanted to access iPad screen from another iPad screen.

Comment: @Dhaval are you sure. The description I quoted sounds exactly the way round you want.

Comment: If I write my requirement in one line then it would be:
**I want to access my iPad from another iPad**

Answer (score -2):

Bombar has ipad support.  It is from a pd or Mac though.  Not from another ipad.

Answer (score -3):

Zoom lets you share pictures, and other thins - but, not the desktop.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on how this answers the question?